# Errors with tensorflow-gpu 2.0alpha0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have installed tensorflow-gpu 2.0alpha0, cudatoolkit 10.0.130, and cudnn 7.5 in a windows 10.

TensorFlow 2.0 works well with CPU, but encounters errors while running with GPU.

Errors messages are as bellow:

```
2019-04-02 23:47:38.646661: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-04-02 23:47:38.666653: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2019-04-02 23:47:38.666842: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

I think the main issue is "Could not dlopen library 'nvcuda.dll'".

However, I have installed the latest NVIDIA driver (version 419.67), and 'nvcuda.dll' can be found in C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll.

Comment: Have you set the path 
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%

Answer (score 0):

Its this method that is failing in Tensorflow:

```
    port::StatusOr<void*> GetDsoHandle(const string& name, const string& version) {
        auto filename = port::Env::Default()->FormatLibraryFileName(name, version);
        void* dso_handle;
        port::Status status =
          port::Env::Default()->LoadLibrary(filename.c_str(), &dso_handle);
        if (status.ok()) {
            LOG(INFO) << "Successfully opened dynamic library " << filename;
            return dso_handle;
    }
```

Basically, it means that Tensorflow can't find nvcuda from the PATH variable in your windows environment. To add the environment variable do the following:

**Windows 10 and Windows 8**

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
4. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, add the path value C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**PS:** Make sure you have installed [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried, but it still does not work. Same errors exist.

Comment: Have you installed cuDNN?